# GA4 custom dimension not setting in reports

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am working on GA4 upgrade and developed the code to setup the connection to GA4 in our application. Connection is successful, we can see the user count in GA4. The issue is, we created the custom dimensions in the GA4 and also did the same in the code. We were able to see the values in the debugger console when we ran the application. But the values still show not set in the reports even after 48 hours. Please let me know if we need to do anything else to get the values populated in the reports. Thanks in advance!

I have checked all the possible scenarios

Comment: You can add more information liked how you created the custom dimension and how is the code implemented. Also about how you check in the debug view.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.